# Removing class from html element with JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have been struggling for 2 days now with removing an added class from an Element.
Checked all over the web, but can not find the answer to the problem.

I can add a class to the navigation and show the submenu that works fine.

Then I want to hide the menu again when a user clicks anywhere in the window, but as soon as I type the code to remove the class, it does not work at all. I am using only Vanilla JS without to look at jquery to master JS first.

Thank you so much in advance, couldn´t find any solution on the web!

https://jsfiddle.net/dx6ofnvs/4/

HTML

```
 <nav> 
  <div class="nav__navigation">
    <ul>
      
      <li id="services__btn"> <a href="#"> Leistungen</a></li>
        <div class="services__dropdown__container">
          <ul id="services__dropdown" class="dropdown">
              <li> <a href="#"> Link one</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#"> Link two</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#"> link three</a></li>
              <li> <a href="#"> link four</a></li>
           
          </ul> 
        </div>
      
   
    
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

CSS

```
const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
const nav = document.querySelector(".nav__navigation");
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav__navigation li");
const servicesBtn = document.querySelector("#services__btn");
const servicesDropdown = document.querySelector("#services__dropdown");
const servicesDropdownContainer = document.querySelector("#services__dropdown__container")
const html = document.querySelector("html")

///// Open Mobile Menu

burger.addEventListener("click", (navSlide));

function navSlide() {
    nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
}



///// Open Dropdown Desktop Width
 servicesBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    servicesDropdown.classList.add("dropdown--active");    
}) 



window.addEventListener("click", (e) => {      
    if(e.target != servicesDropdown) {

/// I think this code ist the problem that it removes the class immedeatly after shown

        servicesDropdown.classList.remove("dropdown--active")
        console.log('clicked');        
    }    
})
```

Comment: After hours and hours of working with the dropdown, I used 

e.stopPropagation()  // and this works!

Is this now a good idea, since I have read it is not always a good use...

Comment: I have just browsed your HTML markup. It seems that you put a `div` element as a direct child of an `ul` element. Such things are not allowed. An `ul` element only takes `li` elements as valid children. Perhaps browsers do not complain, but its not according to specifications, so the behavior is probably completely undefined and unspecified. Who can guarantee that any issues at hand are not caused by this? Please consider to overthink and rewrite your HTML design and make sure it passes the [W3C HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/) (or any other good HTML validator).

Comment: it says `CSS` but I believe you mean `JS`

Comment: `document.querySelector("#services__dropdown__container")` this is wrong, it's a class in your HTML, not an id

Comment: There's a lot of noise in your example, classes not used, unnecessary variables etc. 
 See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example on how to ask questions with a minimal reproducible example. It will greatly improve our ability to help

Comment: @CervEd I am going back to the code to review. The unused classes are from a design which I created, deleted some of the code to reduce confusion. Thank you for your help! This means a lot to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target element in the window function is not the button, is the link. You should check for it instead. I modified your fiddle so you can check it

```
    <li id="services__btn"> <a class="button" href="#"> Leistungen</a></li>

...

window.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let button = document.querySelector(".button");
        if(e.target !== button && servicesDropdown.classList.contains("dropdown--active")) {
            servicesDropdown.classList.remove("dropdown--active")
            console.log('clicked');        
        }
        console.log('e', e.target);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ft2om9ak/1/

Comment: Thank you! I still have to improve...   :(

Answer (score 0):

There exists a (DOM) [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) function for cases like this. Which you can use like this:

```
const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
const nav = document.querySelector(".nav__navigation");
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav__navigation li");
const servicesBtn = document.querySelector("#services__btn");
const servicesDropdown = document.querySelector("#services__dropdown");
const servicesDropdownContainer = document.querySelector(".services__dropdown__container")
const html = document.querySelector("html")

///// Open Mobile Menu

burger.addEventListener("click", (navSlide));

function navSlide() {
    nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
}



///// Open Dropdown Desktop Width
 servicesBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    servicesDropdown.classList.toggle("dropdown--active");    
}) 



document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if(!servicesDropdownContainer.parentNode.contains(e.target) && servicesDropdown.classList.contains("dropdown--active")) {
        servicesDropdown.classList.remove("dropdown--active")
        console.log('clicked');        
    }    
})
```

Also, `services__dropdown__container` is a class and not an id.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Just been trying hard to learn....